# Prevent auto import of PowerShell modules in Azure Automation Runbook

Tags: powershell, azure-automation, azure-runbook, import-module

I have an Azure Automation PowerShell runbook that calls particular child runbooks based on input parameters. The child runbooks perform actions with different PowerShell modules. I believe Azure Automation is automatically loading/importing the required modules at the moment the child runbook is called. I would like to prevent this behaviour, and import modules manually using `import-module`.

**In an Azure Automation account, is it possible to control if/when required modules are imported?**

---

**Edit:**
*[Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/shared-resources/modules#import-az-modules) outlining conditions where modules are imported.*

Comment: Thanks @SagePourpre, this has worked. If you write this as an answer I'd be happy to mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior, in Powershell, is controlled by one of the preference variables. More specifically, the `$PSModuleAutoloadingPreference` variable.

This variable control the automatic importing of module in the session.
By default, it is set to `All`, which automatically import modules on first-use.

Set this to `None` to disable the automatic importing of modules. You will need to explicitely use `Import-Module` for any command to be loaded.

Here's a snippet of the official documentation regarding preferences variiables and that variable specifically.

---

#### About Preference Variables

> PowerShell includes a set of variables that enable you to customize
> its behavior. These preference variables work like the options in
> GUI-based systems.
>
> The preference variables affect the PowerShell operating environment
> and all commands run in the environment. In many cases, the cmdlets
> have parameters that you can use to override the preference behavior
> for a specific command.

...

> #### $PSModuleAutoloadingPreference
>
> Enables and disables automatic importing of modules in the session.
> All is the default. To import a module, get or use any command in the
> module. For example, use Get-Command. The
> $PSModuleAutoloadingPreference variable does not exist by default. The
> default behavior when the variable is not defined is the same as
> $PSModuleAutoloadingPreference = 'All'.
>
> Regardless of the variable's value, you can use Import-Module to
> import a module.
>
> The $PSModuleAutoloadingPreference variable takes one of the
> PSModuleAutoLoadingPreference enumeration values: None,
> ModuleQualified, or All.
>
> Valid values are:
>
> - **All**: Modules are imported automatically on first-use.
> - **ModuleQualified**: Modules are imported automatically only when a user uses the module-qualified name of a command in the module. For
>   example, if the user types MyModule\MyCommand, PowerShell imports the
>   MyModule module.
> - **None**: Automatic importing of modules is disabled in the session. To import a module, use the Import-Module cmdlet.

Source: [about_Preference_Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-7.2#psmoduleautoloadingpreference)